# Application stopped unexpectedly: Fatal Exception

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, fault

could anyone help my with my app code. I tryied to make an application that could send data (number or letter) to arduino through bluetooth. This is how my JAVA code look:

```
package com.example.btprojektas;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

private static final String TAG = "btprojektas";

Button btnON, btnOFF;

BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
BluetoothDevice device = null;
OutputStream outputStream = null;
BluetoothSocket socket = null;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    btnON = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnON);
    btnOFF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOFF);

    if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
        Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
    }

    loadPairedDevice();
    connectBT();

    btnON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendData("0");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn on LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    btnOFF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendData("1");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn off LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private void connectBT() {
    if (device != null) {
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
        try {
            socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            socket.connect();
            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


private void disconnect() {
    try {
        if (outputStream != null) outputStream.close();
        if (socket != null) socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void loadPairedDevice() {
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Device found");

        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
            if (device.getName().equals("HC-06")) {
                this.device = device;
                break;
            }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    disconnect();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    loadPairedDevice();
    connectBT();
}

private void sendData(String message) {
    byte[] buffer = message.getBytes();
    Log.d(TAG,"Send data:"+ message);
    try{
        outputStream.write (buffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {}

}
```

}

in XML I have two buttons. When the program starts I push one of those buttons and the "Applications ... stopped unexpectedly" appears with fatal exeption fault code:

```
01-08 15:55:15.439  15354-15354/com.example.btprojektas E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.btprojektas.MainActivity.sendData(MainActivity.java:122)
        at com.example.btprojektas.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:22)
        at com.example.btprojektas.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:55)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

P.S. Sorry for this question I know that it is quite common but I am new at programming especially JAVA.

Comment: Either `outputStream` or `message` is null when you attempt to access them. By wrapping all of your socket calls in `try {} catch(IOException )` you may be ignoring some vital errors. You should at the very least put a breakpoint on the `e.printStackTrace()` calls. Better would be to actually do something useful in here, i.e. Inform the user that the connection failed

Comment: Check if `device` is not `null`.

Comment: And don't roll over an exception with `catch (IOException e) {}`

Answer (score 0):

It's either the socket or the outputStream. In ConnectBT, you don't check if socket is not null. You directly call socket.connect() assuming socket is valid. The same applies to outputStream. You use it before making sure it's not null.

Also you call

```
startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
```

but you don't check for the result which is whether bluetooth got enabled or not. This makes your device also suspicious.

Calling

```
loadPairedDevice();
connectBT();
```

makes sense only when bluetooth is enabled. Enabling bluetooth can take couple of seconds, but you call them right away.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of tips:

- you're calling loadPairedDevice() and connectBT() twice: in onCreate() and in onResume() - do it only once
- before using outputStream, check if it's not null (as advised by others)
- in sendData(), catch AND print your exception:

  ```
  try {
      if (outputStream != null) {
          outputStream.write(buffer);
      }
      else {
          Log.d("TAG", "sendData() - outputStream is null!");
      }
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```
- in loadPairedDevice(), if you don't find the device "HC-06", your variable device will be null...
- enabling bluetooth takes few seconds, so register and listen to ACTION_STATE_CHANGED broadcast Intent. It will contain extra field EXTRA_STATE; look for STATE_ON, and then call your loadPairedDevices() and connectBT() there:

  - create receiver (inside your MainActivity class):

    ```
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            //this is the action you are observing
            if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
                final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
                switch(state) {
                    //and the state we were looking for
                    //which means that bluetooth has switched on
                    //so now you can call your functions
                    //and set the flag to true, which then use in your
                    //onClick listeners 
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                        loadPairedDevice();
                        connectBT();
                        isBluetoothOn = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ```
  - in onCreate(), create IntentFilter and register receiver with it

    ```
    IntentFilter btFilter = new IntentFilter();
    btFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);

    registerReceiver(mReceiver, btFilter);
    ```
  - remember to unregister receiver in onPause():

    ```
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    ```
- disable your buttons and enable them in the above listener, when you know BT is switched on; alternatively, keep a flag and use it in your click listeners, eg.:

  ```
  boolean isBluetoothOn = false;
  ```

then later in listener when you get STATE_ON

```
isBluetooth = true;
```

And in your button click listener:

```
//for btnON
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (isBluetoothOn) {
        sendData("0");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn on LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Do the same for btnOFF.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I checked if outputStream is not null and I found out that actually it is, now I do not have that "Applications ... stopped unexpectedly" fault when push button. I still have "fatal exception" when running app but I will try to apply other tips it might work.